# Moment.js shows 3 days before today

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, momentjs

In our project (Angular based) we used moment.js for displaying date but it shows 04.10 while today is 07.10

Here is the code:

TS

```
 GetTime(time) {
    const todaysDate = new Date();
    const date = new Date(time);

    const d1 = moment(new Date(todaysDate));
    const d2 = moment(new Date(date));

    const d3 = d1.diff(d2, 'days');

    if (d3 === 0) {
      return moment(time).format('LT');
    } else {
      return moment(time).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    }
  }

HTML

<p class="time float-right">
                        {{GetTime(chat.msgId.message[chat.msgId.message.length - 1].createdAt)}}
                    </p>
```

Why does it show 3 days before now?

Comment: Probably because `time` is 3 days before now, and not now.

Comment: How can be it fixed? Should be it fixed from back-end (Node.js, Mongo DB) or above function is wrong? Because I checked on many devises and everywhere was the same.

Comment: I don't think there is anything that needs to be fixed. If time is 3 days before now, it's normal to have a formatted time which shows 3 days before now. Why don't you show us the value of time?

Comment: What do you mean (if time is 3 days before now)? In All devises time is correct just in this website and mobile apps it shows 04.10.  Really confusing.